# How do I call other Google APIs from a Cloud Function?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I would like to call other Google APIs from my cloud function, for example, to write a file to Cloud Storage after receiving a message from Pubsub.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the [google-cloud client library for Node.js](https://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-node/) to accomplish this. The same library is also available for Java, Python and Ruby.

For example in Node JS, you'll want to edit your package.json file accordingly:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "google-cloud": "*"
  },
  ...
}
```

Then, in your code, you can simply invoke the relevant library.  The following example just lists the buckets in the project:

```
var gcloud = require('google-cloud');

exports.helloworld = function(context, data) {
  var gcs = gcloud.storage({projectId: '<PROJECT>'});    
  gcs.getBuckets(function(err, buckets) {
    if (!err) {
      buckets.forEach(function(bucket) {
        console.log(bucket.name);
      });
    } else {
      console.log('error: ' + err);
    }
  });

  context.success();
}
```

You also shouldn't include the entire `google-cloud` npm module, but instead specify a specific sub-module, e.g. `require('@google-cloud/storage')` in the above example.