# Google Cloud Functions calling approach perfomance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-functions

I found this question. It is about calling other modules inside Google Cloud infrastructure.

[How do I call other Google APIs from a Cloud Function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35351516/how-do-i-call-other-google-apis-from-a-cloud-function?rq=1)

So my question is it possible to trigger Google Cloud Functions using this approach? And how perfromant this solution will be if it is possible?

I think that it probably can be used as code sharing mechanism, because I didn't see any information about this issue regarding GCF.

Answer (score 2):

***Regarding your question about triggering:***  Cloud Functions can be triggered in a variety of ways, including HTTP (web calls such as REST), Pub/Sub, and changes to Cloud Storage (e.g. uploaded files).  The set of triggers is likely to expand over time.  The latest information can be found at https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/calling/

***Regarding your question about performance:*** Cloud Functions, at least the current iteration, run JavaScript inside a Node application. They auto-magically scale. New instances are spun up as demand grows. They should meet the performance needs of most use cases.

***Regarding your comment on code sharing:*** Yes. You could create a function and expose it, such as with HTTP, so that it can be used by multiple applications.  You'll need to do any authentication and authorization checking per call, though.